# Web API2 proxy doesn't redirect the requests

Tags: c#, ajax, cookies, asp.net-web-api, proxy

I have a proxy controller in order to redirect the Ajax requests and pass the same cookies from the current domain to the Web API endpoint, but it doesn't work as what I expected. e.g. the cookies in "https://www.example.com", the Web API URL "https://api.example.com/xyz/abc/". What I am trying to do is sending an Ajax request to

"https://www.example.com/api/proxy/something"

and hoping it to be redirected to

"https://api.example.com/xyz/abc/something" with the same settings (especially the cookies).

Here is the API controller in the web site:

```
public class ProxyController : ApiController
{
    private string _baseUri = "https://api.example.com/xyz/abc/";

    [AcceptVerbs(Http.Get, Http.Head, Http.MkCol, Http.Post, Http.Put)]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Proxy()
    {
        using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
        {
            string proxyURL = this.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
            int indexOfProxy = proxyURL.IndexOf("proxy/") + 6;
            _baseUri = _baseUri + proxyURL.Substring(indexOfProxy, proxyURL.Length - indexOfProxy);
            this.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(_baseUri);

            //For some reason Ajax request sets Content in the Get requests, because 
            //of that it was denied complaining about "cannot send a content-body"
            if (this.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
            {
                this.Request.Content = null;
            }

            return await http.SendAsync(this.Request);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't redirect the requests. In the response, the Requested URL is the same as the original request. The Host in the request header is "www.example.com" instead of "api.example.com', I am going nuts with this issue for the last few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpClient will work fine. We have done this many times. However, cookies are tricky as they are tied to the domain. Here is some code of a proxy without cookies that should get you started.

```
[AcceptVerbs(Http.Get, Http.Head, Http.MkCol, Http.Post, Http.Put)]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Proxy()
{
    var request = this.Request;

    var proxyUri = this.GetProxyUri(request.RequestUri);

    request.RequestUri = proxyUri;
    request.Headers.Host = proxyUri.Host;
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
    {
        request.Content = null;
    }

    //todo: Clone all cookies with the domain set to the domain of the proxyUri. Remove the old cookies and add the clones.

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //default is 60 seconds or so
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        return await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
    }    
}

private string _baseUri = "https://api.example.com/xyz/abc/";

private Uri GetProxyUri(Uri originalUri)
{
    var proxyUri = originalUri.AbsolutePath;
    var indexOfProxy = proxyUri.IndexOf("proxy/") + 6;
    var finalUri = _baseUri + proxyUri.Substring(indexOfProxy, proxyUri.Length - indexOfProxy);
    return new Uri(finalUri);
}
```

You may not be able to get cookies to work properly because of the domain switching. Your client and server will be limited to it's domain. If you own the proxy destination, you may want to change it to allow other mechanisms besides cookies. Can you use headers, or querystring, etc? The domain just may be a killer.

Comment: Just thinking more about the cookies and domains. In your example the top-level-domain is the same, just different sub-domains. If that is the case, just make sure the cookie setter uses cross-domain cookies. This way the cookies will just automatically transfer across. If you are on different domains completely, I don't think cookies will work for you.

Comment: Thanks ManOVision! Yes, the cookie is set for "example.com", and it should work.

Comment: This works as it redirects to the api.example.com, but the cookie for "example.com" doesn't get transferred automatically, do I still need to set it explicitly?

Comment: I do have to set the cookie explicitly, and everything works!! Thanks ManOVision!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this kind of problem like two days ago. 
Haven't figured out exactly what was causing it, I'm going to investigate today and let you know.

But until then, you can try using RestSharp, it fixed my problem.

I think it is a problem with the BaseAddress property of the HttpClient, it somehow gets initialized with the initial address and makes the request to that address instead of the proxy one.

I will investigate and let you know.

Comment: Sounds like we are on the same boat :), actually I was thinking about RestSharp but I haven't tried that for this. I will use RestSharp, hopefully it will work to fix it, still curious why HttpClient doesn't work. Thanks